# IBM Data Studio - Run SQL Shortcut

Tags: ibm-data-studio

Is there any shortcut for the command "Run SQL" in IBM Data Studio Developer 2.1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

F5 works in Data Studio 2.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

F5 still works in Data Studio 4.1.1

Answer (score 0):

F5 works in Data studio 4.1.2 as well.